# AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider not working correctly for Windows Authentication in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, windows, authentication

I am developing an Intranet Application in ASP.NET that uses Windows Authentication. I have created an AD class that gets information from the Active Directory Domain Controller. This is what I use to get things like User Groups that the currently logged user is in. The problem is in the ASP.NET Roles that the user is in. Seems funny, but the list of AD Groups that the user is in is totally different from the list of Roles that the user has.

Here is what I get:

List of AD Groups for a certian user

1. Developers
2. Account Operators
3. Domain Admins
4. IS_IUSRS
5. Administrators

List of the same user's Roles

1. PUDDOM\Domain Users
2. Everyone
3. BUILTIN\Users
4. BUILTIN\Administrators
5. NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE
6. NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
7. NT AUTHORITY\This Organization
8. LOCAL
9. PUDDOM\Domain Admins
10. PUDDOM\Denied RODC Password Replication Group
11. PUDDOM\DnsAdmins

OTHER INFORMATION:

1. I have my website use Integrated Windows Authentication from IIS7.
2. A portion of my `web.config` looks like

this:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"  />
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />

</authorization>

<roleManager defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"  enabled="true">
        <providers>
            <remove name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" />
        </providers>
</roleManager>
```

How do I reconcile the list?

I need to make my Roles list reflect the same data as my AD Groups list because I will use Role trimming in my site map and other stuff.

Answer (score 4):

Part of your result is because some of the groups the user belongs to are members of other groups. The full list of a user's groups will include all groups the user belongs to, both directly and via membership in other groups who are also members.

The list will also include built-in groups that are normally hidden from the native admin tools by default.

Your best bet is to have the application store a master list of the groups you want your application to see, or a list of groups you want your application to ignore (either an include list, or an exclude list). Then when you pull back a specific user's roles, just compare it to the configured exclude or include list and filter out the unwanted results.

If you want an easier way, there is an open source [AD role provider over at codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/active_directory_roles.aspx) that already has support for both exclude and include lists. It also has other nice features like optional caching that will REALLY speed up your application. The build-in AD role provider performs very poorly.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to assign the website permissions specifically to the groups you want to enumerate.

Comment: Please specify how to do this. I think this is my problem and I want to vote you up if this solves it.